# Godot ios templates build - runtime error EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, xcode, build, godot

`OSX 10.14.3 Mojave`
`Xcode 10.3`
`iOS 12.4`

So I've built a godot custom iOS templates on top of the `3.1.1` stable branch which adds [facebook sdk](https://github.com/fogine/godot-facebook) module.
Build is successful and I can use it in editor to export xcode project.
The issues seems to be with `app.pck` file which is exported by godot as part of xcode project.

When I use the exported `*.pck`, the app crashes at runtime after its run with the following error:
`Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)`

**However** when I delete the `app.pck` file and link my Godot project files directly into my xcode project (https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.1/getting_started/workflow/export/exporting_for_ios.html#active-development-considerations), the app does not crash (tested multiple times) and is stable (everything works).

Xcode Crash stack trace:

```js
Breakout`GDScriptFunctions::call:
0x102300bcc <+0>:     sub    sp, sp, #0x180            ; =0x180 
0x102300bd0 <+4>:     stp    d13, d12, [sp, #0xf0]
0x102300bd4 <+8>:     stp    d11, d10, [sp, #0x100]
0x102300bd8 <+12>:    stp    d9, d8, [sp, #0x110]
0x102300bdc <+16>:    stp    x28, x27, [sp, #0x120]
0x102300be0 <+20>:    stp    x26, x25, [sp, #0x130]
0x102300be4 <+24>:    stp    x24, x23, [sp, #0x140]
0x102300be8 <+28>:    stp    x22, x21, [sp, #0x150]
0x102300bec <+32>:    stp    x20, x19, [sp, #0x160]
0x102300bf0 <+36>:    stp    x29, x30, [sp, #0x170]
0x102300bf4 <+40>:    adrp   x8, 4392
0x102300bf8 <+44>:    ldr    x8, [x8, #0x278]
0x102300bfc <+48>:    ldr    x8, [x8]
0x102300c00 <+52>:    str    x8, [sp, #0xe8]
0x102300c04 <+56>:    str    wzr, [x4]
0x102300c08 <+60>:    cmp    w0, #0x59                 ; =0x59 
0x102300c0c <+64>:    b.hi   0x1023035c0               ; <+10740>
0x102300c10 <+68>:    mov    x20, x4
0x102300c14 <+72>:    mov    x19, x3
0x102300c18 <+76>:    mov    x22, x2
0x102300c1c <+80>:    mov    x21, x1
0x102300c20 <+84>:    mov    w8, w0
0x102300c24 <+88>:    adr    x9, #0x4aec               ; <+19268>
0x102300c28 <+92>:    nop    
0x102300c2c <+96>:    ldrsw  x8, [x9, x8, lsl #2]
0x102300c30 <+100>:   add    x8, x8, x9
0x102300c34 <+104>:   br     x8
0x102300c38 <+108>:   ldr    x0, [x21]
0x102300c3c <+112>:   bl     0x103089348               ; Variant::operator double() const
0x102300c40 <+116>:   bl     0x10326399c               ; symbol stub for: sin
0x102300c44 <+120>:   b      0x10230359c               ; <+10704>
0x102300c48 <+124>:   adrp   x8, 4607
0x102300c4c <+128>:   nop    
0x102300c50 <+132>:   ldr    x19, [x8, #0xdc8]
0x102300c54 <+136>:   ldr    x8, [x19]
0x102300c58 <+140>:   ldr    x8, [x8, #0xf8]
0x102300c5c <+144>:   mov    x0, x19
0x102300c60 <+148>:   blr    x8
0x102300c64 <+152>:   cmp    w0, #0x1                  ; =0x1 
0x102300c68 <+156>:   b.lt   0x1023035c0               ; <+10740>
0x102300c6c <+160>:   mov    x20, #0x0
0x102300c70 <+164>:   adrp   x21, 4107
0x102300c74 <+168>:   add    x21, x21, #0xd1d          ; =0xd1d 
0x102300c78 <+172>:   adrp   x22, 4114
0x102300c7c <+176>:   add    x22, x22, #0x130          ; =0x130 
0x102300c80 <+180>:   adrp   x23, 3965
0x102300c84 <+184>:   add    x23, x23, #0x104          ; =0x104 
0x102300c88 <+188>:   adrp   x24, 4107
0x102300c8c <+192>:   add    x24, x24, #0xcc0          ; =0xcc0 
0x102300c90 <+196>:   adrp   x25, 4111
0x102300c94 <+200>:   add    x25, x25, #0xbf           ; =0xbf 
0x102300c98 <+204>:   add    x8, sp, #0x68             ; =0x68 
0x102300c9c <+208>:   mov    x0, x20
0x102300ca0 <+212>:   bl     0x103084e4c               ; itos(long long)
0x102300ca4 <+216>:   add    x1, sp, #0x68             ; =0x68 
0x102300ca8 <+220>:   add    x8, sp, #0x70             ; =0x70 
0x102300cac <+224>:   mov    x0, x21
0x102300cb0 <+228>:   bl     0x103073c30               ; operator+(char const*, String const&)
0x102300cb4 <+232>:   add    x0, sp, #0x60             ; =0x60 
0x102300cb8 <+236>:   mov    x1, x22
0x102300cbc <+240>:   bl     0x1030710b4               ; String::String(char const*)
0x102300cc0 <+244>:   add    x0, sp, #0x70             ; =0x70 
0x102300cc4 <+248>:   add    x1, sp, #0x60             ; =0x60 
0x102300cc8 <+252>:   add    x8, sp, #0x78             ; =0x78 
0x102300ccc <+256>:   bl     0x10306eae0               ; String::operator+(String const&) const
0x102300cd0 <+260>:   ldr    x8, [x19]
0x102300cd4 <+264>:   ldr    x9, [x8, #0x110]
0x102300cd8 <+268>:   add    x8, sp, #0x58             ; =0x58 
0x102300cdc <+272>:   mov    x1, x20
0x102300ce0 <+276>:   mov    x0, x19
0x102300ce4 <+280>:   blr    x9
0x102300ce8 <+284>:   add    x0, sp, #0x78             ; =0x78 
0x102300cec <+288>:   add    x1, sp, #0x58             ; =0x58 
0x102300cf0 <+292>:   add    x8, sp, #0x80             ; =0x80 
0x102300cf4 <+296>:   bl     0x10306eae0               ; String::operator+(String const&) const
0x102300cf8 <+300>:   add    x0, sp, #0x50             ; =0x50 
0x102300cfc <+304>:   mov    x1, x23
0x102300d00 <+308>:   bl     0x1030710b4               ; String::String(char const*)
0x102300d04 <+312>:   add    x0, sp, #0x80             ; =0x80 
0x102300d08 <+316>:   add    x1, sp, #0x50             ; =0x50 
0x102300d0c <+320>:   add    x8, sp, #0xa8             ; =0xa8 
0x102300d10 <+324>:   bl     0x10306eae0               ; String::operator+(String const&) const
0x102300d14 <+328>:   ldr    x8, [x19]
0x102300d18 <+332>:   ldr    x8, [x8, #0x100]
0x102300d1c <+336>:   mov    x1, x20
0x102300d20 <+340>:   mov    x0, x19
0x102300d24 <+344>:   blr    x8
0x102300d28 <+348>:   sxtw   x0, w0
0x102300d2c <+352>:   add    x8, sp, #0x48             ; =0x48 
0x102300d30 <+356>:   bl     0x103084e4c               ; itos(long long)
0x102300d34 <+360>:   add    x0, sp, #0xa8             ; =0xa8 
0x102300d38 <+364>:   add    x1, sp, #0x48             ; =0x48 
0x102300d3c <+368>:   add    x8, sp, #0x28             ; =0x28 
0x102300d40 <+372>:   bl     0x10306eae0               ; String::operator+(String const&) const
0x102300d44 <+376>:   add    x0, sp, #0x40             ; =0x40 
0x102300d48 <+380>:   mov    x1, x24
0x102300d4c <+384>:   bl     0x1030710b4               ; String::String(char const*)
0x102300d50 <+388>:   add    x0, sp, #0x28             ; =0x28 
0x102300d54 <+392>:   add    x1, sp, #0x40             ; =0x40 
0x102300d58 <+396>:   add    x8, sp, #0xb0             ; =0xb0 
0x102300d5c <+400>:   bl     0x10306eae0               ; String::operator+(String const&) const
0x102300d60 <+404>:   ldr    x8, [x19]
0x102300d64 <+408>:   ldr    x9, [x8, #0x108]
0x102300d68 <+412>:   add    x8, sp, #0x18             ; =0x18 
0x102300d6c <+416>:   mov    x1, x20
0x102300d70 <+420>:   mov    x0, x19
0x102300d74 <+424>:   blr    x9
0x102300d78 <+428>:   add    x0, sp, #0xb0             ; =0xb0 
0x102300d7c <+432>:   add    x1, sp, #0x18             ; =0x18 
0x102300d80 <+436>:   add    x8, sp, #0xc8             ; =0xc8 
0x102300d84 <+440>:   bl     0x10306eae0               ; String::operator+(String const&) const
0x102300d88 <+444>:   add    x0, sp, #0x10             ; =0x10 
0x102300d8c <+448>:   mov    x1, x25
0x102300d90 <+452>:   bl     0x1030710b4               ; String::String(char const*)
0x102300d94 <+456>:   add    x0, sp, #0xc8             ; =0xc8 
0x102300d98 <+460>:   add    x1, sp, #0x10             ; =0x10 
0x102300d9c <+464>:   add    x8, sp, #0x20             ; =0x20 
0x102300da0 <+468>:   bl     0x10306eae0               ; String::operator+(String const&) const
0x102300da4 <+472>:   add    x0, sp, #0x20             ; =0x20 
0x102300da8 <+476>:   bl     0x10301d3c4               ; print_line(String)
0x102300dac <+480>:   ldr    x0, [sp, #0x20]
0x102300db0 <+484>:   cbz    x0, 0x102300dd4           ; <+520>
0x102300db4 <+488>:   sub    x8, x0, #0x8              ; =0x8 
0x102300db8 <+492>:   ldaxr  w9, [x8]
0x102300dbc <+496>:   subs   w9, w9, #0x1              ; =0x1 
0x102300dc0 <+500>:   stlxr  w10, w9, [x8]
0x102300dc4 <+504>:   cbnz   w10, 0x102300db8          ; <+492>
0x102300dc8 <+508>:   b.ne   0x102300dd4               ; <+520>
0x102300dcc <+512>:   orr    w1, wzr, #0x1
0x102300dd0 <+516>:   bl     0x103118ff0               ; Memory::free_static(void*, bool)
0x102300dd4 <+520>:   ldr    x0, [sp, #0x10]
0x102300dd8 <+524>:   cbz    x0, 0x102300dfc           ; <+560>
0x102300ddc <+528>:   sub    x8, x0, #0x8              ; =0x8 
0x102300de0 <+532>:   ldaxr  w9, [x8]
0x102300de4 <+536>:   subs   w9, w9, #0x1              ; =0x1 
0x102300de8 <+540>:   stlxr  w10, w9, [x8]
0x102300dec <+544>:   cbnz   w10, 0x102300de0          ; <+532>
0x102300df0 <+548>:   b.ne   0x102300dfc               ; <+560>
0x102300df4 <+552>:   orr    w1, wzr, #0x1
0x102300df8 <+556>:   bl     0x103118ff0               ; Memory::free_static(void*, bool)
0x102300dfc <+560>:   ldr    x0, [sp, #0xc8]
0x102300e00 <+564>:   cbz    x0, 0x102300e24           ; <+600>
0x102300e04 <+568>:   sub    x8, x0, #0x8              ; =0x8 
0x102300e08 <+572>:   ldaxr  w9, [x8]
0x102300e0c <+576>:   subs   w9, w9, #0x1              ; =0x1 
0x102300e10 <+580>:   stlxr  w10, w9, [x8]
0x102300e14 <+584>:   cbnz   w10, 0x102300e08          ; <+572>
0x102300e18 <+588>:   b.ne   0x102300e24               ; <+600>
0x102300e1c <+592>:   orr    w1, wzr, #0x1
0x102300e20 <+596>:   bl     0x103118ff0               ; Memory::free_static(void*, bool)
0x102300e24 <+600>:   ldr    x0, [sp, #0x18]
0x102300e28 <+604>:   cbz    x0, 0x102300e4c           ; <+640>
0x102300e2c <+608>:   sub    x8, x0, #0x8              ; =0x8 
0x102300e30 <+612>:   ldaxr  w9, [x8]
0x102300e34 <+616>:   subs   w9, w9, #0x1              ; =0x1 
0x102300e38 <+620>:   stlxr  w10, w9, [x8]
0x102300e3c <+624>:   cbnz   w10, 0x102300e30          ; <+612>
0x102300e40 <+628>:   b.ne   0x102300e4c               ; <+640>
0x102300e44 <+632>:   orr    w1, wzr, #0x1
0x102300e48 <+636>:   bl     0x103118ff0               ; Memory::free_static(void*, bool)
0x102300e4c <+640>:   ldr    x0, [sp, #0xb0]
0x102300e50 <+644>:   cbz    x0, 0x102300e74           ; <+680>
0x102300e54 <+648>:   sub    x8, x0, #0x8              ; =0x8 
0x102300e58 <+652>:   ldaxr  w9, [x8]
0x102300e5c <+656>:   subs   w9, w9, #0x1              ; =0x1 
0x102300e60 <+660>:   stlxr  w10, w9, [x8]
0x102300e64 <+664>:   cbnz   w10, 0x102300e58          ; <+652>
0x102300e68 <+668>:   b.ne   0x102300e74               ; <+680>
0x102300e6c <+672>:   orr    w1, wzr, #0x1
0x102300e70 <+676>:   bl     0x103118ff0               ; Memory::free_static(void*, bool)
0x102300e74 <+680>:   ldr    x0, [sp, #0x40]
0x102300e78 <+684>:   cbz    x0, 0x102300e9c           ; <+720>
0x102300e7c <+688>:   sub    x8, x0, #0x8              ; =0x8 
0x102300e80 <+692>:   ldaxr  w9, [x8]
0x102300e84 <+696>:   subs   w9, w9, #0x1              ; =0x1 
0x102300e88 <+700>:   stlxr  w10, w9, [x8]
0x102300e8c <+704>:   cbnz   w10, 0x102300e80          ; <+692>
0x102300e90 <+708>:   b.ne   0x102300e9c               ; <+720>
0x102300e94 <+712>:   orr    w1, wzr, #0x1
0x102300e98 <+716>:   bl     0x103118ff0               ; Memory::free_static(void*, bool)
0x102300e9c <+720>:   ldr    x0, [sp, #0x28]
0x102300ea0 <+724>:   cbz    x0, 0x102300ec4           ; <+760>
0x102300ea4 <+728>:   sub    x8, x0, #0x8              ; =0x8 
0x102300ea8 <+732>:   ldaxr  w9, [x8]
0x102300eac <+736>:   subs   w9, w9, #0x1              ; =0x1 
0x102300eb0 <+740>:   stlxr  w10, w9, [x8]
0x102300eb4 <+744>:   cbnz   w10, 0x102300ea8          ; <+732>
0x102300eb8 <+748>:   b.ne   0x102300ec4               ; <+760>
0x102300ebc <+752>:   orr    w1, wzr, #0x1
0x102300ec0 <+756>:   bl     0x103118ff0               ; Memory::free_static(void*, bool)
0x102300ec4 <+760>:   ldr    x0, [sp, #0x48]
0x102300ec8 <+764>:   cbz    x0, 0x102300eec           ; <+800>
0x102300ecc <+768>:   sub    x8, x0, #0x8              ; =0x8 
0x102300ed0 <+772>:   ldaxr  w9, [x8]
0x102300ed4 <+776>:   subs   w9, w9, #0x1              ; =0x1 
0x102300ed8 <+780>:   stlxr  w10, w9, [x8]
0x102300edc <+784>:   cbnz   w10, 0x102300ed0          ; <+772>
0x102300ee0 <+788>:   b.ne   0x102300eec               ; <+800>
0x102300ee4 <+792>:   orr    w1, wzr, #0x1
0x102300ee8 <+796>:   bl     0x103118ff0               ; Memory::free_static(void*, bool)
0x102300eec <+800>:   ldr    x0, [sp, #0xa8]
0x102300ef0 <+804>:   cbz    x0, 0x102300f14           ; <+840>
0x102300ef4 <+808>:   sub    x8, x0, #0x8              ; =0x8 
0x102300ef8 <+812>:   ldaxr  w9, [x8]
0x102300efc <+816>:   subs   w9, w9, #0x1              ; =0x1 
0x102300f00 <+820>:   stlxr  w10, w9, [x8]
0x102300f04 <+824>:   cbnz   w10, 0x102300ef8          ; <+812>
0x102300f08 <+828>:   b.ne   0x102300f14               ; <+840>
0x102300f0c <+832>:   orr    w1, wzr, #0x1
0x102300f10 <+836>:   bl     0x103118ff0               ; Memory::free_static(void*, bool)
0x102300f14 <+840>:   ldr    x0, [sp, #0x50]
0x102300f18 <+844>:   cbz    x0, 0x102300f3c           ; <+880>
0x102300f1c <+848>:   sub    x8, x0, #0x8              ; =0x8 
0x102300f20 <+852>:   ldaxr  w9, [x8]
0x102300f24 <+856>:   subs   w9, w9, #0x1              ; =0x1 
0x102300f28 <+860>:   stlxr  w10, w9, [x8]
0x102300f2c <+864>:   cbnz   w10, 0x102300f20          ; <+852>
0x102300f30 <+868>:   b.ne   0x102300f3c               ; <+880>
0x102300f34 <+872>:   orr    w1, wzr, #0x1
0x102300f38 <+876>:   bl     0x103118ff0               ; Memory::free_static(void*, bool)
0x102300f3c <+880>:   ldr    x0, [sp, #0x80]
0x102300f40 <+884>:   cbz    x0, 0x102300f64           ; <+920>
0x102300f44 <+888>:   sub    x8, x0, #0x8              ; =0x8 
0x102300f48 <+892>:   ldaxr  w9, [x8]
0x102300f4c <+896>:   subs   w9, w9, #0x1              ; =0x1 
0x102300f50 <+900>:   stlxr  w10, w9, [x8]
0x102300f54 <+904>:   cbnz   w10, 0x102300f48          ; <+892>
0x102300f58 <+908>:   b.ne   0x102300f64               ; <+920>
0x102300f5c <+912>:   orr    w1, wzr, #0x1
0x102300f60 <+916>:   bl     0x103118ff0               ; Memory::free_static(void*, bool)
0x102300f64 <+920>:   ldr    x0, [sp, #0x58]
0x102300f68 <+924>:   cbz    x0, 0x102300f8c           ; <+960>
0x102300f6c <+928>:   sub    x8, x0, #0x8              ; =0x8 
0x102300f70 <+932>:   ldaxr  w9, [x8]
0x102300f74 <+936>:   subs   w9, w9, #0x1              ; =0x1 
0x102300f78 <+940>:   stlxr  w10, w9, [x8]
0x102300f7c <+944>:   cbnz   w10, 0x102300f70          ; <+932>
0x102300f80 <+948>:   b.ne   0x102300f8c               ; <+960>
0x102300f84 <+952>:   orr    w1, wzr, #0x1
0x102300f88 <+956>:   bl     0x103118ff0               ; Memory::free_static(void*, bool)
0x102300f8c <+960>:   ldr    x0, [sp, #0x78]
0x102300f90 <+964>:   cbz    x0, 0x102300fb4           ; <+1000>
0x102300f94 <+968>:   sub    x8, x0, #0x8              ; =0x8 
0x102300f98 <+972>:   ldaxr  w9, [x8]
0x102300f9c <+976>:   subs   w9, w9, #0x1              ; =0x1 
0x102300fa0 <+980>:   stlxr  w10, w9, [x8]
0x102300fa4 <+984>:   cbnz   w10, 0x102300f98          ; <+972>
0x102300fa8 <+988>:   b.ne   0x102300fb4               ; <+1000>
0x102300fac <+992>:   orr    w1, wzr, #0x1
0x102300fb0 <+996>:   bl     0x103118ff0               ; Memory::free_static(void*, bool)
0x102300fb4 <+1000>:  ldr    x0, [sp, #0x60]
0x102300fb8 <+1004>:  cbz    x0, 0x102300fdc           ; <+1040>
0x102300fbc <+1008>:  sub    x8, x0, #0x8              ; =0x8 
0x102300fc0 <+1012>:  ldaxr  w9, [x8]
0x102300fc4 <+1016>:  subs   w9, w9, #0x1              ; =0x1 
0x102300fc8 <+1020>:  stlxr  w10, w9, [x8]
0x102300fcc <+1024>:  cbnz   w10, 0x102300fc0          ; <+1012>
0x102300fd0 <+1028>:  b.ne   0x102300fdc               ; <+1040>
0x102300fd4 <+1032>:  orr    w1, wzr, #0x1
0x102300fd8 <+1036>:  bl     0x103118ff0               ; Memory::free_static(void*, bool)
0x102300fdc <+1040>:  ldr    x0, [sp, #0x70]
0x102300fe0 <+1044>:  cbz    x0, 0x102301004           ; <+1080>
0x102300fe4 <+1048>:  sub    x8, x0, #0x8              ; =0x8 
0x102300fe8 <+1052>:  ldaxr  w9, [x8]
0x102300fec <+1056>:  subs   w9, w9, #0x1              ; =0x1 
0x102300ff0 <+1060>:  stlxr  w10, w9, [x8]
0x102300ff4 <+1064>:  cbnz   w10, 0x102300fe8          ; <+1052>
0x102300ff8 <+1068>:  b.ne   0x102301004               ; <+1080>
0x102300ffc <+1072>:  orr    w1, wzr, #0x1
0x102301000 <+1076>:  bl     0x103118ff0               ; Memory::free_static(void*, bool)
0x102301004 <+1080>:  ldr    x0, [sp, #0x68]
0x102301008 <+1084>:  cbz    x0, 0x10230102c           ; <+1120>
0x10230100c <+1088>:  sub    x8, x0, #0x8              ; =0x8 
0x102301010 <+1092>:  ldaxr  w9, [x8]
0x102301014 <+1096>:  subs   w9, w9, #0x1              ; =0x1 
0x102301018 <+1100>:  stlxr  w10, w9, [x8]
0x10230101c <+1104>:  cbnz   w10, 0x102301010          ; <+1092>
0x102301020 <+1108>:  b.ne   0x10230102c               ; <+1120>
0x102301024 <+1112>:  orr    w1, wzr, #0x1
0x102301028 <+1116>:  bl     0x103118ff0               ; Memory::free_static(void*, bool)
0x10230102c <+1120>:  add    x20, x20, #0x1            ; =0x1 
0x102301030 <+1124>:  ldr    x8, [x19]
0x102301034 <+1128>:  ldr    x8, [x8, #0xf8]
0x102301038 <+1132>:  mov    x0, x19
0x10230103c <+1136>:  blr    x8
0x102301040 <+1140>:  cmp    x20, w0, sxtw
0x102301044 <+1144>:  b.lt   0x102300c98               ; <+204>
0x102301048 <+1148>:  b      0x1023035c0               ; <+10740>
0x10230104c <+1152>:  cmp    w22, #0x0                 ; =0x0 
0x102301050 <+1156>:  b.le   0x102302e90               ; <+8900>
0x102301054 <+1160>:  cmp    w22, #0x3                 ; =0x3 
0x102301058 <+1164>:  b.lt   0x102303604               ; <+10808>
0x10230105c <+1168>:  adrp   x8, 4169
0x102301060 <+1172>:  ldr    d0, [x8, #0x380]
0x102301064 <+1176>:  str    d0, [x20]
0x102301068 <+1180>:  b      0x1023030c8               ; <+9468>
0x10230106c <+1184>:  ldr    x0, [x21]
0x102301070 <+1188>:  ldr    w8, [x0]
0x102301074 <+1192>:  cmp    w8, #0x4                  ; =0x4 
0x102301078 <+1196>:  b.ne   0x1023030b4               ; <+9448>
0x10230107c <+1200>:  str    xzr, [sp, #0xb0]
0x102301080 <+1204>:  add    x8, sp, #0xc8             ; =0xc8 
0x102301084 <+1208>:  bl     0x103088cec               ; Variant::operator String() const
0x102301088 <+1212>:  add    x0, sp, #0xc8             ; =0xc8 
0x10230108c <+1216>:  add    x2, sp, #0xb0             ; =0xb0 
0x102301090 <+1220>:  add    x3, sp, #0x28             ; =0x28 
0x102301094 <+1224>:  mov    x1, x19
0x102301098 <+1228>:  bl     0x10317343c               ; JSON::parse(String const&, Variant&, String&, int&)
0x10230109c <+1232>:  mov    x20, x0
0x1023010a0 <+1236>:  ldr    x0, [sp, #0xc8]
0x1023010a4 <+1240>:  cbz    x0, 0x1023010c8           ; <+1276>
0x1023010a8 <+1244>:  sub    x8, x0, #0x8              ; =0x8 
0x1023010ac <+1248>:  ldaxr  w9, [x8]
0x1023010b0 <+1252>:  subs   w9, w9, #0x1              ; =0x1 
0x1023010b4 <+1256>:  stlxr  w10, w9, [x8]
0x1023010b8 <+1260>:  cbnz   w10, 0x1023010ac          ; <+1248>
0x1023010bc <+1264>:  b.ne   0x1023010c8               ; <+1276>
0x1023010c0 <+1268>:  orr    w1, wzr, #0x1
0x1023010c4 <+1272>:  bl     0x103118ff0               ; Memory::free_static(void*, bool)
0x1023010c8 <+1276>:  cbz    w20, 0x1023010ec          ; <+1312>
0x1023010cc <+1280>:  str    wzr, [sp, #0xc8]
0x1023010d0 <+1284>:  add    x1, sp, #0xc8             ; =0xc8 
0x1023010d4 <+1288>:  mov    x0, x19
0x1023010d8 <+1292>:  bl     0x1030900ac               ; Variant::operator=(Variant const&)
0x1023010dc <+1296>:  ldr    w8, [sp, #0xc8]
0x1023010e0 <+1300>:  cbz    w8, 0x1023010ec           ; <+1312>
0x1023010e4 <+1304>:  add    x0, sp, #0xc8             ; =0xc8 
0x1023010e8 <+1308>:  bl     0x103088824               ; Variant::clear()
0x1023010ec <+1312>:  ldr    x0, [sp, #0xb0]
0x1023010f0 <+1316>:  cbz    x0, 0x1023035c0           ; <+10740>
0x1023010f4 <+1320>:  sub    x8, x0, #0x8              ; =0x8 
0x1023010f8 <+1324>:  ldaxr  w9, [x8]
0x1023010fc <+1328>:  subs   w9, w9, #0x1              ; =0x1 
0x102301100 <+1332>:  stlxr  w10, w9, [x8]
0x102301104 <+1336>:  cbnz   w10, 0x1023010f8          ; <+1324>
0x102301108 <+1340>:  b      0x102303dec               ; <+12832>
0x10230110c <+1344>:  str    xzr, [sp, #0xb0]
0x102301110 <+1348>:  ldr    x0, [x21]
0x102301114 <+1352>:  add    x1, sp, #0xb0             ; =0xb0 
0x102301118 <+1356>:  mov    x2, #0x0
0x10230111c <+1360>:  mov    x3, #0x0
0x102301120 <+1364>:  bl     0x1030faad8               ; VariantWriter::write_to_string(Variant const&, String&, String (*)(void*, Ref<Resource> const&), void*)
0x102301124 <+1368>:  add    x0, sp, #0xc8             ; =0xc8 
0x102301128 <+1372>:  add    x1, sp, #0xb0             ; =0xb0 
0x10230112c <+1376>:  bl     0x1030922ec               ; Variant::Variant(String const&)
0x102301130 <+1380>:  add    x1, sp, #0xc8             ; =0xc8 
0x102301134 <+1384>:  mov    x0, x19
0x102301138 <+1388>:  bl     0x1030900ac               ; Variant::operator=(Variant const&)
0x10230113c <+1392>:  ldr    w8, [sp, #0xc8]
0x102301140 <+1396>:  cbz    w8, 0x10230114c           ; <+1408>
0x102301144 <+1400>:  add    x0, sp, #0xc8             ; =0xc8 
0x102301148 <+1404>:  bl     0x103088824               ; Variant::clear()
0x10230114c <+1408>:  ldr    x0, [sp, #0xb0]
0x102301150 <+1412>:  cbz    x0, 0x1023035c0           ; <+10740>
0x102301154 <+1416>:  sub    x8, x0, #0x8              ; =0x8 
0x102301158 <+1420>:  ldaxr  w9, [x8]
0x10230115c <+1424>:  subs   w9, w9, #0x1              ; =0x1 
0x102301160 <+1428>:  stlxr  w10, w9, [x8]
0x102301164 <+1432>:  cbnz   w10, 0x102301158          ; <+1420>
0x102301168 <+1436>:  b      0x102303dec               ; <+12832>
0x10230116c <+1440>:  ldr    x0, [x21]
0x102301170 <+1444>:  ldr    w8, [x0]
0x102301174 <+1448>:  cmp    w8, #0x12                 ; =0x12 
0x102301178 <+1452>:  b.ne   0x102303224               ; <+9816>
0x10230117c <+1456>:  add    x8, sp, #0xb0             ; =0xb0 
0x102301180 <+1460>:  bl     0x10308c830               ; Variant::operator Dictionary() const
0x102301184 <+1464>:  adrp   x1, 3985
0x102301188 <+1468>:  add    x1, x1, #0x2d7            ; =0x2d7 
0x10230118c <+1472>:  add    x0, sp, #0xc8             ; =0xc8 
0x102301190 <+1476>:  bl     0x103092350               ; Variant::Variant(char const*)
0x102301194 <+1480>:  add    x0, sp, #0xb0             ; =0xb0 
0x102301198 <+1484>:  add    x1, sp, #0xc8             ; =0xc8 
0x10230119c <+1488>:  bl     0x102fd1804               ; Dictionary::has(Variant const&) const
0x1023011a0 <+1492>:  mov    x21, x0
0x1023011a4 <+1496>:  ldr    w8, [sp, #0xc8]
0x1023011a8 <+1500>:  cbz    w8, 0x1023011b4           ; <+1512>
0x1023011ac <+1504>:  add    x0, sp, #0xc8             ; =0xc8 
0x1023011b0 <+1508>:  bl     0x103088824               ; Variant::clear()
0x1023011b4 <+1512>:  tbz    w21, #0x0, 0x102303934    ; <+11624>
0x1023011b8 <+1516>:  adrp   x1, 3985
0x1023011bc <+1520>:  add    x1, x1, #0x2d7            ; =0x2d7 
0x1023011c0 <+1524>:  add    x0, sp, #0xc8             ; =0xc8 
0x1023011c4 <+1528>:  bl     0x103092350               ; Variant::Variant(char const*)
0x1023011c8 <+1532>:  add    x0, sp, #0xb0             ; =0xb0 
0x1023011cc <+1536>:  add    x1, sp, #0xc8             ; =0xc8 
0x1023011d0 <+1540>:  bl     0x102fd141c               ; Dictionary::operator[](Variant const&)
0x1023011d4 <+1544>:  add    x8, sp, #0xa8             ; =0xa8 
0x1023011d8 <+1548>:  bl     0x103088cec               ; Variant::operator String() const
0x1023011dc <+1552>:  adrp   x1, 3974
0x1023011e0 <+1556>:  add    x1, x1, #0x390            ; =0x390 
0x1023011e4 <+1560>:  add    x0, sp, #0x80             ; =0x80 
0x1023011e8 <+1564>:  bl     0x1030710b4               ; String::String(char const*)
0x1023011ec <+1568>:  add    x0, sp, #0xa8             ; =0xa8 
0x1023011f0 <+1572>:  add    x1, sp, #0x80             ; =0x80 
0x1023011f4 <+1576>:  add    x8, sp, #0x28             ; =0x28 
0x1023011f8 <+1580>:  mov    w2, #0x0
0x1023011fc <+1584>:  mov    x3, #0x0
0x102301200 <+1588>:  bl     0x1031a0bec               ; ResourceLoader::load(String const&, String const&, bool, Error*)
0x102301204 <+1592>:  ldr    x23, [sp, #0x28]
0x102301208 <+1596>:  cbz    x23, 0x1023041fc          ; <+13872>
0x10230120c <+1600>:  adrp   x1, 4523
0x102301210 <+1604>:  add    x1, x1, #0x8              ; =0x8 
0x102301214 <+1608>:  adrp   x2, 4523
0x102301218 <+1612>:  add    x2, x2, #0x20             ; =0x20 
0x10230121c <+1616>:  mov    x0, x23
0x102301220 <+1620>:  mov    x3, #0x0
0x102301224 <+1624>:  bl     0x1032628d4               ; symbol stub for: __dynamic_cast
0x102301228 <+1628>:  mov    x21, x0
0x10230122c <+1632>:  cbz    x0, 0x1023044f8           ; <+14636>
0x102301230 <+1636>:  mov    x0, x21
0x102301234 <+1640>:  bl     0x10303290c               ; Reference::reference()
0x102301238 <+1644>:  ldr    x23, [sp, #0x28]
0x10230123c <+1648>:  mov    x22, x21
0x102301240 <+1652>:  cbnz   x23, 0x1023044fc          ; <+14640>
0x102301244 <+1656>:  mov    x22, x21
0x102301248 <+1660>:  b      0x102304534               ; <+14696>
0x10230124c <+1664>:  ldr    x0, [x21]
0x102301250 <+1668>:  bl     0x103089348               ; Variant::operator double() const
0x102301254 <+1672>:  mov.16b v8, v0
0x102301258 <+1676>:  ldr    x0, [x21, #0x8]
0x10230125c <+1680>:  bl     0x103089348               ; Variant::operator double() const
0x102301260 <+1684>:  mov.16b v9, v0
0x102301264 <+1688>:  ldr    x0, [x21, #0x10]
0x102301268 <+1692>:  bl     0x103089348               ; Variant::operator double() const
0x10230126c <+1696>:  fsub   d0, d0, d9
0x102301270 <+1700>:  fcvt   s1, d0
0x102301274 <+1704>:  fabs   s1, s1
0x102301278 <+1708>:  fcvt   d1, s1
0x10230127c <+1712>:  adrp   x8, 4165
0x102301280 <+1716>:  ldr    d2, [x8, #0x6b0]
0x102301284 <+1720>:  fcmp   d1, d2
0x102301288 <+1724>:  b.mi   0x1023017f0               ; <+3108>
0x10230128c <+1728>:  fsub   d1, d8, d9
0x102301290 <+1732>:  fdiv   d1, d1, d0
0x102301294 <+1736>:  frintm d1, d1
0x102301298 <+1740>:  fmul   d0, d0, d1
0x10230129c <+1744>:  fsub   d9, d8, d0
0x1023012a0 <+1748>:  b      0x1023017f0               ; <+3108>
0x1023012a4 <+1752>:  ldr    x0, [x21]
0x1023012a8 <+1756>:  ldr    w8, [x0]
0x1023012ac <+1760>:  cmp    w8, #0x11                 ; =0x11 
0x1023012b0 <+1764>:  b.ne   0x102303238               ; <+9836>
0x1023012b4 <+1768>:  bl     0x10308c794               ; Variant::operator Object*() const
0x1023012b8 <+1772>:  mov    x20, x0
0x1023012bc <+1776>:  adrp   x21, 4607
0x1023012c0 <+1780>:  add    x21, x21, #0xc10          ; =0xc10 
0x1023012c4 <+1784>:  ldr    x0, [x21]
0x1023012c8 <+1788>:  ldr    x8, [x0]
0x1023012cc <+1792>:  ldr    x8, [x8]
0x1023012d0 <+1796>:  blr    x8
0x1023012d4 <+1800>:  adrp   x10, 4607
0x1023012d8 <+1804>:  add    x10, x10, #0xc00          ; =0xc00 
0x1023012dc <+1808>:  ldr    x8, [x10]
0x1023012e0 <+1812>:  cbz    x8, 0x1023056c0           ; <+19188>
0x1023012e4 <+1816>:  mvn    x9, x20
0x1023012e8 <+1820>:  add    x9, x9, x20, lsl #18
0x1023012ec <+1824>:  eor    x9, x9, x9, lsr #31
0x1023012f0 <+1828>:  mov    w11, #0x15
0x1023012f4 <+1832>:  mul    x9, x9, x11
0x1023012f8 <+1836>:  eor    x9, x9, x9, lsr #11
0x1023012fc <+1840>:  add    x9, x9, x9, lsl #6
0x102301300 <+1844>:  lsr    x11, x9, #22
0x102301304 <+1848>:  eor    w9, w11, w9
```

What could be the cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be fixed in `3.1` godot branch.
The crash happens when building against `3.1.1-stable` tag.